# Unable to do media only screens (max width and max-device-width)

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following media only screen

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) and (max-device-width:768px) {
```

it does not work when i try to do both of them. If i only do max-width then it works.

Comment: [`device-width` was deprecated in Media Queries Level 4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to just use `max-width`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
...
}
```